# Empty list and character when scraping in rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

```
library('rvest')

player <- html("http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/dejounte-murray-1.html")

advanced <- html_nodes(player, "#players_advanced .right")

html_text(advanced)

/## results in character(0)

advanced

/## results in list(), attr(,"class"), [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

The problem arises from this website when I try to pull an table but the basic one, AKA html_nodes(player, "#players_per_game .right"). Why am I having trouble pulling other data from this site? On the help and examples online, I have no problems pulling extra data from their sites.

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you expect the output to be in this case?

Comment: The same as if you did the basic table of players_per_game. A list of values from the table. So in my code if you swap one for one #players_advanced and #players_per_game you get a non-empty list and the characters from the table.